# Query to retrive name and highest sal of employee in particular month

Tags: postgresql

I have two table emp and salary.

```
select * from emp;
 id  |  name  
 -----+--------
 111 | Ashika
 222 | banu
 333 | charu
 444 | dhji

select * from salary;
 id  | sal_id | month |  sal  
 -----+--------+-------+-------
 111 |      1 | jan   | 15000
 111 |      2 | dec   | 14000
 111 |      3 | nov   | 14000
 222 |     13 | jan   | 14000
 222 |     12 | Dec   | 14000
 333 |     22 | Dec   | 14000
 333 |     23 | jan   | 16000
 444 |     33 | jan   | 12000
```

I want to get the name of employee who have got maximun salary in "jan" month.

I have tired the follwing query in postgres:

```
select name,max(sal) as sal from Empp join Salary using(id)where month='jan' group by name;

 name  |  sal  
--------+-------
 charu  | 16000
 Ashika | 15000
 dhji   | 12000
 banu   | 14000

 select max(sal) from (select name,max(sal) as sal from Empp join Salary using(id)where month='jan'group by name) as foo;
  max  
 -------
 16000
(1 row)
```

I want name and salary to be retrieved from table.

```
Excepted output:
name  |  sal  
-------+-------
charu | 16000
```

Comment: Why is only one record being returned here?  What is the logic?  More than one employee receieved their maximum salary in January.

Comment: I just want to list  the name of the employee who is getting maximum sal in "jan" month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.name, s.sal
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.sal DESC) rn
    FROM emp e
    INNER JOIN salary s
        ON e.id = s.id
    WHERE s.month = 'jan'
)

SELECT name, sal
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Running the above command i get the output as   :name  |  sal  --------+-------
            Ashika | 15000
 banu   | 14000
 charu  | 16000
 dhji   | 12000
(4 rows)

Answer (score 1):

@ishika, I think you're asking the query which don't use 'With' keywork.

Here is the updated answer:-
   1. With using CTE

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT e.name, s.salary
 FROM emp e
 INNER JOIN salary s
  ON e.id = s.emp_id    
 WHERE s.month = 'jan'  
)     
SELECT top 1 name, salary
FROM cte order by salary desc
```

2. Without using CTE

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, salary 
FROM (SELECT e.name, s.salary
      FROM emp e
      INNER JOIN salary s
      ON e.id = s.emp_id    
      WHERE s.month = 'jan') my_selected_data
ORDER BY salary DESC
```

Comment: can i get the query with using the keyword "WITH"

Comment: @ishika, I didn't get your query.

Comment: It almost answers.... Is it possible to get the query without using ("Top"  and  "desc" )or atleast("top")......Sorry there is lot of constraints given to me in writing the query....Thanks in advance

Comment: `TOP` is invalid for Postgres (or in standard SQL)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH result AS 
(SELECT e.name, s.sal  FROM empp e 
INNER JOIN 
salary s ON e.id = s.id WHERE s.month = 'jan')
SELECT name,sal FROM result 
where sal = (select max(sal) from (select name,max(sal) as sal 
from Empp join Salary using(id)where month='jan' 
group by name) as foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest query:

```
SELECT E1.name, S1.sal FROM Empp E1 INNER JOIN salary S1 ON E1.id = S1.id where 
S1.sal = (select max(S2.sal) from Salary S2
where S2.month='jan');
```

output:

```
name  |  sal  
-------+-------
charu | 16000
(1 row)
```